# update CCK field using Execute Custom PHP in rule drupal 6

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I am new to drupal so need help. I am trying to write a RULE which will run a **PHP code** on trigger of a event. (Its working fine. Event gets triggered)

I have a created a custom content type. I have added few contents to this content type. Now I am trying to update these contents in that **PHP code**, however its not working.

My query is as follows,

$ctag = $ctag+1;

db_query("UPDATE {content_type_phone_user} SET field_puser_ctag_value=%d WHERE nid=%d", $ctag, $puser['nid']);

**And I noticed something weird here.**

The above code works for the first time. However if you try again it doesnt update the column in table.

But if I login as admin and than just click on save button of this content type (without making any changes), and try running this PHP script again, database gets updated (But works only once and I ahve to do the above process everytime)

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

At last I could find the answer,

Instead of writing the quesry, we just need to load the node that we are trying to update using

**$node = node_load(nid);**

Than set the new value to the column that need updation as

**$node->field_dm_puser_ctag[0]['value'] = $ctag;**

Than save this node using

**node_save($node);**

Which is equivalent to update query.

Hurray :)